# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel vs Model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

For the sake of maintaining best practices regarding centralizing data and for my own convenience I'm trying to find out what's the best way of model validation.

So there's this simple question - say that I'm setting up a "create account" form and I want my 'LastName' field to be required. Should I rather use [Required] on my model or the current ViewModel?

I know that theoretically it all depends on the logic I want to implement, i.e. if on my every website I run a policy where 'last name' is a required field, I might want to add it to the model and be done with it, whereas if it's a case-specific scenario - ViewModel is the way to go.

Having that said let's assume the scenario no. 1 (i.e. always required) is the case and data validation goes to the model. There's still this little problem of user input going to the ViewModel. The first solution I can think of is making the model one of ViewModel's properties, which doesn't seem very elegant.

Another thing might involve letting the ViewModel know about the validation during its setup (via reflection), but, don't get me wrong, there's got to be a simpler way of doing this.

Would be greatful for any kind of help provided, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You add it to both

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay.
Could you elaborate on it a bit?